# Access VBA - Add number to cell in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm exporting to Excel and I need to insert numbers in front of cells that allready have numbers in It. Here is my full code:

```
Private Sub cmdExport_Click()

Dim Results  As Recordset
Dim Numbering  As Integer

Dim FileName As String
Dim FilePath As String

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim XcelFile As Excel.Application

FileName = "TEST" & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & ".xlsx"

FilePath = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & FileName

 Set XcelFile = New Excel.Application

 Set wb = XcelFile.Workbooks.Add

 Set Results  = Forms![MyForm].Form.RecordsetClone

   With wb

      XcelFile.ScreenUpdating = False

      For Numbering = 0 To Results.Fields.Count - 1
      XcelFile.Cells(1, Numbering + 1).Value = Results.Fields(Numbering).Name
      Next Numbering

      Results.MoveFirst
      XcelFile.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset Results

     For Each cell In XcelFile.Range("A:A")
     cell.Value = "100" & cell.Value
     Next cell

      .SaveAs FileName:=FilePath, FileFormat:=51
      XcelFile.ScreenUpdating = True

   End With

  wb.Close
  Set XcelFile = Nothing

  End Sub
```

As you see, I have tried with this:

```
For Each cell In XcelFile.Range("A:A")
         cell.Value = "100" & cell.Value
         Next cell
```

But, unfortunally, nothing happens. How could I solve this?

Comment: It would be simpler to query the data you want from your database, prepend the 100 in the query and then just drop the results straight into Excel.

Comment: Maybe, I haven't tried this, but now I have this and wish to solve It.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each cell In XcelFile.Range("A:A")
```

should be

```
Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
Set sh = wb.ActiveSheet
For Each cell In sh.Range("A:A")
```

me thinks.

This applies for all other places where you have `XcelFile.Cells` now, change them to `sh.Cells`.

Note:

```
Dim XcelFile As Excel.Application
```

is a really really confusing name, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks Andre, I changed everything and It works. What about If want to add this in end of rows - this doesn't work for me : For Each cell In sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row